# Get all nodes along a path

Tags: neo4j

So over the past few days I started learning about Neo4j and graph databases. The main motive behind this is to easily perform some graph traversal operations which I've done in relational databases before and were not very pleasant to deal with to say the least.

Anyway, I've inserted some data into the DB and now I'm trying to write queries to get the data I'm interested in. So far, this what I have:

[image]

I've written the below query to get all the nodes starting at `University` all the way to `Computer Science` (check image below the snippet)

`MATCH path = (:University)-[*]->(d:Department {Code: 'cs'}) WHERE d.Code = 'cs' RETURN path`

[image]

But unfortunately, the `Faculty of Economics` node is not being returned with the result although it's a child of node `Institution 1`.

Actual result I'm getting:

[image]

So where did I go wrong?

Comment: You have stated what is wrong, but not what you are trying to do. Are you trying to get *all* the paths rooted at a node with the `University` label, or something else?

Comment: I'm trying to get ALL the nodes along the path from `University` to a given node, which in this case is the `Computer Science` node. The nodes I expect to be returned are the ones in the red circle above.

Comment: But the economics node is NOT along the path to the CS node, any more than than the Life Sciences node is.